# (file_get_contents) get all variables instant

Tags: php, regex

```
<?php

$text = file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1/text.php');

$start = '<span class="ip">';
$end = '</span>';

$start_p = strpos($text, $start);
$end_p = strpos($text, $end);

$text_p = $end_p - $start_p;

$cut = substr($text, $start_p, $text_p);
$cut = str_replace($start,"",$cut);

$msg = $cut;

echo $msg;

?>
```

text.php:

```
<?php
<span class="ip">11.11.11.11</span>
<span class="ip">22.22.22.22</span>
<span class="ip">33.33.33.33</span>
<span class="ip">44.44.44.44</span>
<span class="ip">55.55.55.55</span>
<span class="ip">66.66.66.66</span>
?>
```

I want to get all possible variables starting `<span class="ip">` and ending with`</span>`. With this script i managed to get only one variable that is 11.11.11.11. Any ideas how to output all of them instant? Thx for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**preg_match_all**](http://php.net/preg_match_all) instead, capturing all the required data with a single line of code:

```
preg_match_all('/<span class="ip">([^<]*)<\/span>/', $text, $m);
$ips = $m[1]; 
var_dump($ips); // ['11.11.11.11', '22.22.22.22'...]
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/81480). Here I've used the regular expression to match `<span>...` part - and capturing group to extract the data into `$m` variable.

Comment: Thank you, you saved me a lot of time.